# Derive asymptotic behaviour of $k:=k(n)$ from $2^k/k<n$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Let $k:=k(n)$ be a function that satisfies
$$ \frac{2^k}{k}<n.$$
I'm trying to show that
$$ k<\log_{2}n+\log_{2}\log_{2}n + \mathcal{O}(1).$$

If I take $\log$ on both sides I get that
$$ k-\log_2 k < \log_2 n,$$
therefore, it suffices to show that $\log_2 k = \log_2\log_2 n + \mathcal{O}(1).$ To that end, I've tried to take the log one more time (but I'm not sure where it goes).
$$\log_{2}\left(k\left(1-\frac{\log_{2} k}{k}\right)\right)\approx\log_{2}k-\frac{\log_{2}k}{k}=\log_{2}k\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\leq \log_2 k\cdot e^{-k}.$$
Where the first approximation relies on $\ln(1+x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^{-2})$, for $x$ small enough.

Comment: Just for your interest: $$
k < \log _2 n + \log _2 \log _2 n + \frac{{\log _2 \log _2 n}}{{\log _2 n}} \cdot \ln 2 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\left( {\frac{{\log _2 \log _2 n}}{{\log _2 n}}} \right)^2 } \right).
$$

Comment: @Gary Does it follow from my calculation below if I stick the big-oh instead of replacing it with the little-oh? Can you elaborate on how you developed that or give a source?

Comment: I solved $n=\frac{2^k}{k}=\frac{e^{k\ln 2}}{k\ln 2}\cdot\ln 2$ asymptotically for $k\ln 2$ using the results discussed in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1006/jsco.1994.1014). You can obtain more terms if you like.

Comment: @Gary, Can you mention which theorem are you citing from this paper, I got a little lost.

Comment: You can just look at the front page. $x=n$, $y=k\ln 2$, $d_0=\ln 2$, $d_1=d_2=\ldots=0$. The theorem is Theorem $1$.

Comment: @Gary, Thanks a lot, I never used this method. May I ask that you will make the full development (maybe as another answer)? Anyway, I really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining my thoughts with Fred's answer.
Note that
$$
\ln\left(x-\ln\left(x\right)\right)=\ln\left(x\left(1-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)\right)=\ln x-\frac{\ln x}{x}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln^2 x}{x^2}\right)=\ln x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\right)\right)=\ln x\left(1-o\left(1\right)\right).
$$
Similarly, one can derive that
$$
\log_{2}\left(k-\log_{2}\left(k\right)\right)=\log_{2}\left(k\right)\cdot\left(1-o\left(1\right)\right).
$$
Therefore, taking $\log$ on both sides of $k-\log_2 k < \log_2 n$ and substituting the above yields
\begin{align*}
\log_{2}\left(k\right)\cdot\left(1-o\left(1\right)\right)<\log_2 \log_2 n &\implies \log_2 k <(1+o(1))\log_2\log_2 n\\
&\implies \log_2 k< \log_2\log_2 n+\mathcal{O}(1).
\end{align*}
The results follow.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was missing, thanks! That's what I get for trying to answer at 4am...

Answer (score 2):

For large enough $k$, as $k$ increases, $\log_2\left(k-\log_2k\right)$ tends towards $\log_2k$ from below. So, there is some constant $C>0$ so that $\log_2k <\log_2\left(k-\log_2k\right) + C$. This just needs to be greater than the maximum distance between $\log_2\left(k-\log_2k\right)$ and $\log_2k$ (which is finite, since one tends to the other asymptotically).

So, since $k - \log_2k < \log_2n$, taking logs of both sides gives $\log_2\left(k-\log_2k\right) < \log_2\log_2n$, and combining with the earlier inequality gives $\log_2k < \log_2\log_2n + C$.

Putting all the inequalities together, we have $k < \log_2k +\log_2n < \log_2n + \log_2\log_2n + C$, as required.

Comment: "(which is finite, since one tends to the other asymptotically)" That isn't true for all asymptotics, here it is true because $\log_2(k−\log_2k) - \log_2k = \log_2(1-\frac{log_2k}{k})$ which converges to $0$

Comment: @EnEm sorry, I don't follow - could you clarify? Perhaps there is a typo in your comment, or maybe I misunderstood. I'd be happy to edit my answer if there is an issue!

Comment: @FredT For example, $1/\ln x$ tends to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity. However, the maximum distance between $y=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} 1/\ln x - 0 = \infty$, contradicting the quote that the distance is finite. Yet, we can say that from some point the distance is finite.

Comment: @ProperIllumination No, that is not what I meant. I meant like take $n$ and $n+\log_2(n)$, their distance $=n+log_2(n)-n=log_2(n)$ is not finite from any point. But still they tend to the other asymptotically because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\log_2(n)}{n}=1$

Comment: @EnEm I formalized the answer below.